# Using data from an array without foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a function in my Model:

```
 public function get_learning_category_list() {
 $categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
        ->from('learning_category t1')
        ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
        ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
        ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
        ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('t1.id')
        ->get()->result_array();
    foreach($categorias as $c){
        $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
        ->from('learning')
        ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
        ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

        $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
        $tt = $c['title'];
        $url = $c['url'];
        if($this->language != 'pt_br'){
            $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
            $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
        }

        $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);

    }

    return $return; //$categorias;
}
```

It results in me an Array with the learnings list:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados [id] => 2 [total] => 6 [title_pt_br] => ) [1] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Cursos de Social Media Marketing [id] => 3 [total] => 2 [title_pt_br] => ) [2] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Cursos de SEO e otimização de sites [id] => 4 [total] => 3 [title_pt_br] => )
```

But I need to use the data from these learnings (title, id, etc.) in another function in Model:

```
public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) {
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    print_r($categorias);
    foreach($categorias as $cat){
        print_r($cat);
        $cat = (object) $cat;
        if($cat->title != '') {


            $return = strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
        }else{
            $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
        }   
    return $return;   
    }
```

I did so, but with the foreach always results in the same independent data which page I am. How can I use the data from this array without foreach?

Comment: looking at the code, the `return` is inside the foreach loop

Comment: sorry, I'm new in programming. I put the return out?

Comment: if you intend to process all items inside the array, then you need to take that outside, after you are done, then return your intended result

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to check whether the `$category` is inside those `titles` that you fetched from that model, then you could just continually check, if its okay, then convert the title and return it, if not, then return the default.

```
public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) 
{
    // what does this block do
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US') {
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    }
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US') {
        $lang_domin = 'es/';
    }

    $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    $title = '';
    foreach($categorias as $cat) {
        // if its inside titles (checker)
        if($cat['title'] == $category) {
            $title = strtolower(url_title($title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat['id'];
            return $title;
        } else {
            $title = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat['id']; 
        }

    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: I will explain you all my aim for clarity. What I am doing is a function to see if the url of the site is correct, this function will set the format of the url, in which case it would be `(the title) .'- CMDO -'.(The id)` So what I need is to recover the title and the id according to the learning that is. You See?

Comment: @GWER okay, that means you'll have to check each element title inside the array if this title is indeed correct? most probably, you'll need another function inside the `foreach` loop, if its correct, then make it look like a `url_title`, if not, use the default one. so in the end you'll have a collection of verified titles, right?

Comment: This is my function that checks if the url is correct, it makes a comparison with the result of url_format_category function and redirects to the correct url if it is wrong: `if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin)) {
  redirect($this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin),'location','301');
   exit;` I think now became clearer. I already have a function that checks whether she's right. Only need to set the url like this: `(Title).'-cmdo-'.(Id)` or `cursos-sobre-como-gerar-leads-qualificados-cmdo-2`

Comment: @GWER wait a minute.... why is `url_format_category` called twice? its recursively calling the same function

Comment: i do not understand your question

Comment: this redirection function is in my controller, and that sets the url in Model